# R-exams: How to change margins in exams2nops()?

Tags: r-exams

I would like to prepare an exam using exams2nops() function. However, I want to change margins in a questions section. I tried to modify the header argument in the exams2nops function to:
`exams2nops(...header = "\\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}"...)`
however it only had an effect on a first page.  I do not know how to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NOPS format is not written in such a way that it is intended to make modifications to the page layout. In particular, the exam sheet that is to be scanned, must not be modified because otherwise the scanning may be problematic. Also, the `{geometry}` package is not used but all the classic parameters like `{oddsidemargin}` and `{evensidemargin}` are set directly.

If you want to make changes to any of these you should not make them in the `header = ...` already (because these might also affect the exams sheet) but you can try making them in the `intro = ...` (after the exam sheet(s) have been written). For example, you could do:

```
exams2nops(..., intro = "\\setlength{\\oddsidemargin}{1cm}")
```

However, depending on how complext the format is you are looking for, it might not be straightforward to set all parameters correspondingly.